# React executing set state twice despite being called once

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i tries to update array using previous state, set state is being executed twice.

```
const [countries,setCountries] = useState(["usa","china","russia"])
const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(0)

const updateCountries = () => {
  console.log("I should be printed once and being printed ONCE")
  setCountries(previous => {
    console.log("I should be printed once but being printed TWICE")
    return previous.map(country => {
      setUpdated(prev => prev+1)
      return country
    });
  })
  console.log(updated)
  // 6
}
```

While using current state fixes this issue :

```
const updateCountries = () => {
  console.log("I should be printed once and being printed ONCE")
  setCountries(countries.map(country => {
    setUpdated(prev => prev+1)
    return country
  }))
  console.log(updated)
  // 3
}
```

am i missing some react rules while using previous state?

Update : I have been unable to reproduce this behaviour in other react components. So it might be other code of component that is triggering this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: `countries` _isn't_ initially an array, you call `useState` with three separate parameters (two of which are ignored).

Comment: @jonrsharpe typo mistake... but question is still same.

Comment: Please give a [mre] that people can actually _run_, at least a component we can drop into a basic CRA framework or something. And double-check for [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Comment: console.log("I should be printed once but will be printed TWICE") will print exactly once.  https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shockley-gl26t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry i don't know how to create react snippets on stackoverflow. tried few time but getting errors.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/3001761. Or just a whole component that can be copy-pasted, rather than random snippets (which, based on your comment below, do **not** contain whatever's actually causing this).

Comment: its not to do with array, in other components of my app array states are getting updated fine without triggering map function twice. let me try to create snippets again

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question is wrong.. its not to do with array.. i have to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: This is why we ask for a MRE to start with - it's basic debugging, and if you'd done it you'd have known your assumption about where the issue is was wrong before getting to post the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i m coding for years now.. but still don't know how to debug even html. actually i m an illitrate farmer in india.. never did any job related to coding.. so don't know much about debugging and testing.

Comment: We can't tell whether or not you _can_ debug, but the fact that you didn't provide an MRE and have now had to try to retract the question tells us that, in this case at least, you _didn't_. Note the guidance in [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe this problem still exists in my component and i also found an alternate solution very early on but still for 5-6 hours i tried to figure out the root cause before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609549/how-to-update-array-created-with-usestate-hook-in-react

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say 100% without the full code but it seems that your code triggers a rerender and that is why setCountries runs twice. It shouldn't have anything to do with the array but rather with the sequence you run things.

If you place the setCountry and setCountries outside a useEffect you will most likely trigger infinite rerenders which you don't want.

What you probably want is something like the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState(['usa','china','russia']);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('');

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCountries(previous => {
      console.log("I should be printed once and I am printed once", previous);
      const newArray = [...previous];
      newArray.push(country);
      return newArray;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)} value={country} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Country</button>
      <ul>
        {countries && countries.map(c => <li key={c}>{c}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: These setStates are called inside manually triggered functions. But yes Its not to do with array because in other components of my app it executes once for arrays too.

Comment: @fishLegs cool. I simplified the answer so that you don't need to use useEffect. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Also keep in mind that each time you set a value that uses useState a rerendering is triggered. If you then need to run some code that will affect other variables you need to do these operations within a useEffect hook that runs after the rerendering. Make sure you read about hooks and you understand how it works.

Comment: i know very well about hooks.. working with react hooks for years

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is causing 2 re-renders to your component. One with setCountry, second - with setCountries.

Comment: thx for pointing out but setStates are called inside manually triggered function